# LDAP Spring Security using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

I have overridden method to connect mine ldap server for authenticating:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("CN={0},OU=Users,OU=MyWorld,OU=Asia Pacific,DC=myworld,DC=com")
            .groupSearchBase("OU=Asia Pacific,DC=myworld,DC=com")
            .contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://myworld.com:389"), "DC=myworld,DC=com");
}
```

But when I'm providing username and passowrd I'm getting exception saying:`Reason: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580];`

Comment: Can you verify that your LDAP server is working correctly? The best thing to do would be to write a simple LDAP client in Java and using that for authentication.

Comment: Yes I have checked, LDAP server is working properly.